# Reverse proxy to direct different name to different ports

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

We have 2 DNS names (call them D1 and D2) pointing to the same IP address (call it A).  At A there are 2 webservers on different ports (say 8081 and 8082).  I need to configure that the 2 names point to the 2 webservers eg D1 points A:8081 and D2 pints to A:8082.  I think this is simple but have not been able to work out how to configure Apache or Nginx as reverse-proxy to do this.  (This is just so users don't have to type a port number.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two DNS names, so that will be implemented in Nginx as two `server` blocks with different `server_name` statements. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name d1.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
server {
    server_name d2.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
    }
}
```